# REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_X_FORWARDER, action_dispatch.remote_ip - differences and access in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, http-headers, user-agent

I'm doing integration of vbulletin forum and my rails app.

I need to get request ip to create some hashes. I found some article with tips how to do this using php's `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ATTR']` to get this ip, which should be `request.env['REMOTE_ATTR']` in Rails.

Unfortunatelu on both production and development I get `127.0.0.1`, so I checked `request.env`, and found that real request ip is in `'HTTP_X_FORWARDER'` and `'action_dispatch.remote_ip'`.

Now in a view I tried to output both:

`<%= request.env['action_dispatch.remote_ip']%>` outputs correct ip.

`<%= request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDER']%>` outputs blank.

It's strage as `<%= debug request.env %>` shows me that `'HTTP_X_FORWARDER'` value is requested ip address.

Do you know why `REMOTE_ADDR` is always `127.0.0.1`, and `'HTTP_X_FORWARDER'` outputs blank?
And is it ok, to use `'action_dispatch.remote_ip'` to get this request ip?